# Creating a Boxplot with the leftmost column on Y axis

Tags: r, dataframe, data-science, boxplot

[image: Data Frame]

How can I make a Boxplot using the leftmost column as the Y axis, and each of the cells represent the frequency of each of X1, X2, etc... for the column header? Like this:

[image: Target]

Comment: Two things, please: (1) Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272. (2) Wow that image is huge, makes reading the question for context a little difficult. Can you shrink that boxplot image a bit, please? (More #1 than #2, but still ... :-)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for

```
d <- data.frame(c(0,5,17,32,13), c(9,11,20,14,13))
x <- -10
for (i in 1: length(d[,1])) {
  y <- rep(i, d[i,1])
  x <- c(x, y)
}
x <- x[-which(x == -10)]
boxplot(x)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but how can I iterate through every column to have all the box plots for each column side by side?

Comment: ggplot2 will be better for showing multiple plots on the same graph. to iterate through each column put the code in a for loop (aka x[j] where j is the column number)